# Using select value as operator

Tags: javascript

How can I use the select's value as operator for making some calculations?

```
<select id="operation">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
</select>
```

How can I use `op` to calculate between value A and B?

```
var op = document.getElementById('operation').value;
```

Is there another way then using a `switch()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
var operators = {
    '+': function(a, b) { return a + b },
    '-': function(a, b) { return a - b },
    '*': function(a, b) { return a * b },
    '/': function(a, b) { return a / b }
};

var op = '+';
alert(operators[op](10, 20));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try eval

```
eval("x = A" + op + "B");
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object to map values to functions:

```
var operators = {
    '+': function(x, y) { return x + y; },
    '-': function(x, y) { return x - y; },
    '*': function(x, y) { return x * y; },
    '/': function(x, y) { return x / y; }
};

var result = operators[op](A, B);
```