# adding / dividing / multiplying numbers and operators from array in javascript without eval()

Tags: javascript, arrays, eval, calculator, equation

I'm making a calculator. And the challenge is not to use `eval()`. I made an array from all the inputs that looks like this:

```
numbers = [1,1,'+',2,'*',3,'-','(',4,'*',5,'+',2,'/',5,')'];
```

Then i convert this array to a string, remove the , and i get a string like this:

```
numberString = "11+2*3-(4*5+2/5)";
```

So my question is, what is the way to correctly calculate the result of this equation without using `eval()`?

Comment: You can't put arithmetic operators in an array like that, aren't you getting a syntax error? You need to make it a string with quotes. `'+'`.

Comment: It does, but it's just like a part of text to formulate my question, not a code to run. I'll update the question for it not to be misleading :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202716/using-select-value-as-operator/21202809#21202809 for how to map operator strings to functions that implement that operation.

Comment: Really? You don't use eval for the "challenge" but now you're asking for the solution here? Try it yourself and read the forum rules before you post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object to map operator strings to functions that implement the operator.

```
var operators = {
    '+': function(x, y) { return x + y; },
    '-': function(x, y) { return x - y; },
    '*': function(x, y) { return x * y; },
    '/': function(x, y) { return x / y; }
};
```

The `(` function should push the state onto a stack, and `)` should pop the stack.

Comment: Thank You. I'll try to look deeper into the link You suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202716/using-select-value-as-operator/21202809#21202809

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```js
function notEval(fn) {
  return new Function('return ' + fn)();
}
numbers = [1, 1, '+', 2, '*', 3, '-', '(', 4, '*' , 5, '+', 2,' /', 5, ')'];
console.log( numbers.join('') + ' = ' +  notEval(numbers.join('')) );
```

[**Courtesy**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082175/1479535).

Comment: Space magic :)) I'll have to get a better look at this to fully understand how it works..

Comment: Constructing a function is equivalent to using `eval`, it's just different syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I didn't know that. So does that means the same cons of `eval` applies here too?

Comment: Yes, it has all the same problems. They both run the Javascript interpreter over the string.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the info man. So do we need to have some kind of custom interpreter for solving this?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of the exercise, to figure out how to write that interpreter? See my answer for the basics.